# Why post works and get is throwing error? Angular service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I need to get total orders from specific user,

here is my service code /when I am using get/:

```
  getTotal(userId:string): Observable<OrderTransaction[]> {
    const apiUrl = environment.apiUrl + '/OrderTransaction/GetAllByUserId';
    return this._http.get<OrderTransaction[]>(apiUrl, userId)
      .catch(
        (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          return Observable.throw(error);
        });
  }
```

It says:

[image]

Why this happening?

When I change `_http.get` to `_http.post` it works, and why is that?

Thanks guys
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works because `POST` in Angular `HttpClient` accepts as second parameter a body which can be a string which is not a case with a `GET` request. This accepts an object of type HttpParams.

To GET specific data you can use HttpParams, see below:

```
let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append('userId', userId);
return this.httpClient
    .get(this.url, {params});
```

Comment: and it is ok to get data with post?

Comment: Well, how the name says it is supposed to be used to POST and store data, but obviously you can set your server to send specific data back but this would not be considered good practice at all, so please use GET to get data and just attach params to it like shown above.